# Apache Spark Error Could not find or load main class C:\spark\jars\aircompressor-0.8.jar

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Apache spark & recently installed it, but I got an error:

```
**Error: Could not find or load main class C:\spark\jars\aircompressor-0.8.jar**
```

I checked that file it present there, I set up environment variable and all stuff which is necessary to successfully run spark.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you give us some information on how you installed Spark? Where did you get Spark from? And other information you think that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and solved it by updating my installation of java here: https://www.java.com/en/download/.

I upgraded to version 8, Update 201

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this might answer the question, it would be more useful if you added which version resulted in the error for you, and which version solved it for you.